# Select items containing a specific number of a given character (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

For a table like this:

```
visits  url
594     http://example.com/page1/stuff
302     http://example.com/page2
494     http://example.com
202     http://example.com/page3/stuff/more
```

I would like to select only the urls that contain 4 `/` characters.

In python I would use `len(url.split('/')) == 5`. How can this be done in an SQL query?

Comment: can they be consecutive as well with no characters in between? for eg: `http://example.com///`

Comment: sure - so in your example we would count 5

Comment: how about `length(url)-len(replace(url,'/',''))=4`?

Comment: That works. The table has O(10^8) rows so speed is important here, if you can thing of anything that may be faster please share. Cheers. (PS I think your `len` should be `length`)

Comment: There's no fast way to do it, it can't be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of search can't be indexed, so there's no way to optimize it. One way is with a regular expression:

```
WHERE url REGEXP '^([^/]*/){4}[^/]*$'
```

Explanation:

- `^` = beginning of string
- `[^/]*/` = 0 or more non-`/` characters followed by `/`
- `(...){4}` = exactly 4 repetitions of the pattern inside the parentheses
- `[^/]*` = another sequence of non-`/` characters
- `$` = end of string